# How to install refinerycms to my ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, refinerycms

I am working in `'rails', '4.1.10'` and I want to build a CMS for my app so I used `gem 'refinerycms'`

Then in the terminal:

```
brew install imagemagic
gem install refinerycms
```

What should I do after that?

when I put `http://localhost:3000/refinery`, it give me

> No route matches [GET] "/refinery"

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/332-refinery-cms-basics  hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the guide you need > [**Link**](http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started)

The next step should be to generate something with RefineryCMS!

In the terminal type.

**$ refinerycms rickrockstar**